# std::out_of_range exception weird output

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

So I have this function in a template class:

```
T getValue(int x, int y) const throw(logic_error, out_of_range) { // value getter
    try {
        if (x > rows || y > cols || x <= 0 || y <= 0)
            throw out_of_range("Invalid x or y.");
        else
            return data[cols*(x-1)+(y-1)];
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The exception works if I try giving it an out of range number, but the output is always:

```
Invalid x or y.
1
```

I've been trying for an hour to figure out where does that 1 come from, what in the world am I missing? It certainly has something to do with std::out_of_range, but I cannot find out what exactly.

**EDIT** It's about a template matrix:

```
Matrix<int> a(2, 2, 0); // creates a 2x2 matrix of all zeros
cout << a.getValue(3, 2) << endl; // prints the value at row 3, col 2, which doesn't actually exists; the output is as shown above
```

Also, it's worth noting that

```
int b = a.getValue(3, 2);
```

gives the expected output:

```
Invalid x or y.
```

Comment: Add `return 3;` just before the closing curly brace in `getValue` and run the code again. That should make it clear what's going on.

Comment: Did it; the number in the output is now 3, so that 1 I was getting was a sort of rogue return value. Why am I getting that? Aren't exceptions supposed to help me avoid returning any value if the function cannot continue?

Comment: @Zelethil -- the code catches the exception. Normal execution continues after the catch clause. And, yes, the 1 was a sort of rogue return value. Running off the end of a function that's supposed to return a value produces undefined behavior. In practice, you end up seeing whatever value happened to be in the register where the return value is expected.

Comment: Alright, I understand; how can I fix this problem? I was told that using exceptions would help me avoid returning a value, but if the functions returns something anyway, how am I supposed to *not* return any value?

Comment: Don't catch the exception, or catch it and rethrow it. But most important, find a good textbook. This is basic stuff, and you won't learn it by making random experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding

```
exit(-1);
```

to the catch block:

```
catch (out_of_range &e) {
   cerr << e.what() << endl;
   exit(-1);
}
```